# Check substring in dataframe column by referencing string position

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing, substring

I have a dataframe with a column called 'id', where each id is 9 characters long, and I'm trying to add a column 'Rating' where I rate each row as A, AA, or AAA based on whether the 6th, 7th and 8th characters are 'A00', 'AA0' or '000'. I've got the following code so far:

```
id = df['id']
conditions = [(id.str.get(5) == 'A00'), (id.str.get(5) == 'AA0'), (id.str.get(5) == '000')]
values = ['A', 'AA', 'AAA']
df['Rating'] = np.select(conditions, values)
df['Rating'] = df['Rating'].astype('category')
```

But I know the conditions line is wrong because the column.str.get(n) only checks the (n-1)th character of the string and I need the substring of length 3 rather than just a single character. Does anyone know which command I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you always know where it is you can just do id[5:8]  - 5index to 8index ...

Comment: So `000` == `AAA`?

Comment: @mac13k yep, sorry for the confusion haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replace()` with value mappings.:

```
df.id.str[-4:-1].replace({'A00': 'A', 'AA0': 'AA', '000': 'AAA'})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! When I use this and print this out, I just get a series of NaN values - do you know why this is?

Comment: I would need to see your data. It worked for me when I had a dataframe with `['A00', 'AA0', 'AAA']` in the id column.

Comment: But I just checked again and it should work with strings of variable lengths, because only the last 3 chars are checked anyway.

Comment: Ah see I'm not wanting to check the last 3 characters, but the 3 characters before the last (if that makes sense)? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: OK, so you can change the index in get from `[-3:]` to `[-4:-1]'. Also make sure you do have A's in the your id column, otherwise you will get NaNs.

Comment: Edit made, please try it now.

Comment: No worries, just figured it out using @Cptmaxon's comment

Answer (score 0):

Just extract it using a regular expression.

```
df.id.str.extract(r'.{5}([A]+)').fillna('AAA')
```

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['12345A003', '12345AA03', '123450003']}) 
df.id.str.extract(r'.{5}([A]+)').fillna('AAA')
```

Output

```
     0
0    A
1   AA
2  AAA
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! When I use this and print this out, I just get a series of NaN values - do you know why this is?

Comment: Can you print your df['id']?

Comment: Hi just seen your edit - unfortunately my ID numbers are 9 characters long rather than 8, and I'm looking to get the strings from the not the last 3 characters, but the 3 second to last characters if that makes sense (so not the 7th, 8th, 9th, but the 6th, 7th, 8th)

Comment: I've just edited the post with a picture of df['id']

Comment: It has 000 no A003, AA03, or AAA3. If you have entries,  the code just ignores the first 5 characters, it should extract A, AA, AAA out.

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to do is if it has '000', then the rating should be 'AAA'

Comment: No worries, just figured it out using @Cptmaxon's comment

Comment: Code above works. If it is 000, it will be replaced with 'AAA'.